# Cloudfront how to avoid If-Modified-Since header request everytime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, ttl, if-modified-since

AWS Cloudfront document says:

> If you set the TTL for a particular origin to 0, CloudFront will still
>   cache the content from that origin. It will then make a GET request
>   with an If-Modified-Since header, thereby giving the origin a chance
>   to signal that CloudFront can continue to use the cached content if it
>   hasn't changed at the origin

I need to configure my Dynamic Content. I have already set TTL to 0.. I want every request to go to Origin always. Is there a way I avoid this additional GET request with an If-Modified-Since header ! Why this extra request everytime !

Comment: What's the origin? If the origin returns an object with appropriate headers CloudFront will respect that.

Comment: Origin is AWS ELB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way I avoid this additional `GET` request

It sounds as if you are misinterpreting the what you are reading.  Unfortunately, you didn't cite the source, so it's difficult to go back and pick up more context; however, this is not referring to an "extra" request.

> It will then make a `GET` request with an If-Modified-Since header

This refers to **each time the object is subsequently requested by a browser**.  CloudFront sends the **next** request with `If-Modified-Since:` so that your origin server has the *option* of returning a `304 Not Modified` response... it doesn't send two requests to the origin in response to one request from a browser.

If your content is always dynamic, return `Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store` and set Minimum TTL to 0.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationDownloadDist

Comment: Yes content is always dynamic..I don't think setting anything on response like Cache-control etc.. will change things.. Suppose browser makes request which goes to CF ..now CF makes first If-Modified-Since request and then makes another request.. So, I feel there has to be some config on CF where I mention; just always go to origin

Comment: You may think that, but it is still true.  The documentation, at the link provided, is also very clear. If Minimum TTL is set to 0 *and* the origin server sends `Cache-Control: no-cache`, then CloudFront will **"respect the header"** -- and not cache the content.  If it does not cache the content, then sending an `If-Modified-Since` request would be impossible and subsequent requests will simply go to the origin.

Comment: I also suspect you misunderstand how `If-Modified-Since` works.  If CloudFront sends a request for a page `If-Modified-Since` then the origin has two choices: respond `200 OK` along with the new content, or respond `304 Not Modified` with *no content* since this is directing the cache to use the old content. Either way, only one request occurs.  There is no second request.

Comment: Firstly thanks Michael for looking into it.. Both of these last two comments makes sense; but don't you think they are bit of contradicting each other.  Are you sure If-Modified-Since which is NOT GET request ; can get 200 as the response ! Also, as I can see you are MySQL expert; can u take a quick look at stackoverflow.com/questions/40055423

Comment: It **is still** a `GET` request.  `If-Modified-Since` is an attribute of a `GET` (or `HEAD`) request.  *"The `If-Modified-Since` header field makes a `GET` or `HEAD` request method conditional on the selected representation's modification date being more recent than the date provided in the field-value. Transfer of the selected representation's data is avoided if that data has not changed."* -- [RFC-7323](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-3.3) -- Otherwise, of course, transfer is not avoided, because such as request is otherwise treated as a normal `GET` (or `HEAD`) request.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer I got from AWS:

> However, if you forward all headers for that particular origin, the
>   request will go to the origin every time without the If-Modified-Since
>   header mentioned [1]. Please view the excerpt from the link below for
>   further detail:
>
> “Forward all headers to your origin Important If you configure
>   CloudFront to forward all headers to your origin, CloudFront doesn't
>   cache the objects associated with this cache behavior. Instead, it
>   sends every request to the origin.”